# How to make use of IOptions covariance through dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have a small console application, written  in dotnet core 3.1, where I read configurations like this

```
configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
   .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
   .Build();
```

The configuration class is something like

```
public class MyConfiguration
{
    public EmailOptions Email{ get; set; }
    public PhoneOptions Phone{ get; set; }
}
```

`EmailOptions` and `PhoneOptions` contain only properties and the appsettings.json looks like

```
{ "Email": {
  ...
  },
  "Phone": {
  ...
  }
}
```

I want to make use of the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options) and I also want to get the configurations from the dependency injection service so I register the configurations like this

```
serviceCollection
    .AddOptions()
    .Configure<MyConfiguration>(configuration);
```

I access the settings from a class:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public emailOptions { get; private set; }

   public MyClass(IOptions<MyConfiguration> configuration)
   {
      emailOptions = configuration.CurrentValue.EmailOptions;
   }
}
```

So far, all is working, however, one can notice that I pass all the configurations including the `PhoneOptions` to MyClass.

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptions-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) the type parameter of `IOptions` is covariant, so I could write something like

`public MyClass(IOptions<EmailOptions> configuration)`
however, in that case `EmailOptions` won't match the appsettings.json values.

I figured that if I register `EmailOptions` and `PhoneOptions` directly then I have a working solution and I do not need to pass all the configuration values to `MyClass`

```
serviceCollection
    .AddOptions()
    .Configure<EmailOptions>(configuration.GetSection("Email"))
    .Configure<PhoneOptions>(configuration.GetSection("Phone"));
```

The question is that do I really need to register every configuration section one-by-one? What if I have another class within `EmailOptions`? I'd avoid copy-pasting lots of lines of code.

Comment: From the docs you linked to `This type parameter is covariant. That is, you can use either the type you specified or any type that is more derived`.  `EmailOptions` is not **derived** from `MyConfiguration`. You may need to revisit your understanding of [covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)

Comment: With the default DI container, you will need to register everything that needs to be explicitly injected into a dependent class

Comment: You are right, I don't know how I could interpret covariance in a wrong way. Thank you [Nkosi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5233410/nkosi)